# Align cell javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using javascript to add rows to a table dynamically:

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("bestelling");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-5);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var bedrag = document.createElement("input");
    bedrag.type = "text";
    bedrag.name = "bedrag[]";
    cell1.appendChild(bedrag);
}
```

This seems to work perfectly, except I want the first cell to align right. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try adding this (I am assuming that cell1 is the "first cell" that you are referring to):

```
cell1.style.textAlign = "right";
```

This styles the cell with CSS textAlign right.

---

Alternatively, you can set a class name to the cell with this JavaScript code:

```
cell1.className = "alignRight"
```

And use CSS to set the align right.

```
.alignRight{
     text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: That was indeed what i was looking for sir!

Answer (score 0):

To make this even simpler, you could use jQuery - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

```
$("<tr id='new-row'>").insertBefore("#first-row")      // # is the id selector
```

Then you can set the style and content of `#new-row` using the `html()` and `css()` methods:

```
$("#new-row").css("text-align","right");
$("#new-row").html("Hello world!");
```

Hope this helps.